# Iterator Class Design in C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector, iterator

I am trying to learn the concept of writing a generic iterator in C++. I came across this example given below. I don't understand the use of having `NameCollection::value_type` here. Why can't we have 
`Iterator<value_type>` since its a templated class.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class Iterator {
 public:
 typedef T value_type;
 virtual bool hasNext() = 0;
 virtual T next() = 0;
};

class NameManager {
 typedef vector<string> NameCollection;
 NameCollection m_names;
 public:
 class NameIterator: public Iterator< NameCollection::value_type > {
        friend class NameManager;
 private:
        NameManager::NameCollection & m_names;
        NameManager::NameCollection::iterator m_itr;
        NameIterator(NameManager::NameCollection & names) : m_names(names), m_itr(m_names.begin()) {}
 public:
        virtual bool hasNext() {
                return m_itr!=m_names.end();
        }
        virtual NameIterator::value_type next(void) {
                NameIterator::value_type value = (*m_itr);
                ++m_itr;
                return value;
        }
 };
 void addName(NameCollection::value_type name){
        m_names.push_back(name);
 }
 NameIterator getNameIterator(void) {
        return NameIterator(m_names);
        }
 };

int main(void) {
        NameManager nameMgr;
        nameMgr.addName("Jobs");
        nameMgr.addName("Bill");
        nameMgr.addName("Larry");

        NameManager::NameIterator nameItr = nameMgr.getNameIterator();

        while(nameItr.hasNext()) {
                cout<<nameItr.next() << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what kind of problem you are seeing. What would you expect to be used in place of `NameCollection::value_type`?

Comment: `I don't understand the use of having NameCollection::value_type here` ... `NameIterator: public Iterator< NameCollection::value_type >` just translates to `NameIterator : public Iterator < std::string >` since `NameCollection` is a `std::vector<std::string>` and `value_type` refers to the `T` template parameter passed in (the `std::string`) .. What I'm not clear on is what the `NameManager` class is trying to accomplish by teaching generic iterators .. it just wraps what the `std::vector` does and presents it in a different way .. ??

Comment: @n.m. I don't understand what is the difference between NameIterator: public Iterator< NameCollection::value_type> and NameIterator: public Iterator< value_type>

Comment: There is no global `value_type`. What `Iterator< value_type>` could possibly mean?

Comment: @n.m. Does the NameCollection::value_type statement implicitly mean that the Iterator is a std::string since we have a vector<std::string>?

Comment: The iterator *parameter* is `std::string` in this particular case, but prefer using `NameCollection::value_type` anyway. The collection type or the element type may change. `std::string` may have to be changed if this happens, potentially in many places in the code. `NameCollection::value_type` will stand.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are writing generic code which should be able to work with any (or at least generic) iterators. Think about something from the `<algorithm>`. Such a code might be interested in the type of value (type of the expression `*it`). So `value_type` typedef is a standard interface to pass around this information.

---

NameCollection::value_type is std::string, of course. It can serve the same purpose: assume you want to change your underplaying container to use wide strings, or something else. Now if you use std::string explicitely, you will have to find and replace it everywhere. If you use NameCollection::value_type only one line has to be changed.

You can use it in the function 'next' as well (it will work), but semantically it makes much more sense to use iterator there, since this function is all about iterators.

Comment: I understand why there is value_type. My question is what does NameCollection::value_type mean? Its being used in the Iterator expression as well in the function addName. Also in the fuction next why do we need NameIterator::value_type value, can we use NameCollection there?